# SharedElementTransition on fragment dont work

Tags: java, android, animation, fragment, transition

I want to add shared element transition to items in a recyclerview which will opened on another fragment, but nothing works.

The only view that i want to share is an ImageView.

ImageViews and Textviews inside recyclerview items are loaded using Glide for images and firebase database methods for texts. In the detailed fragment, the bitmap of recyclerview item is passed and only the text is downloaded again.

the method which opens the new fragment from recyclerview items is :

```
homeUserAnnouncesAdapter.setOnCardAnnounceClickedListener(new OnCardAnnounceClickedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCardClicked(CardRentAnnounce card, ImageView imageView, int poz) {
            Log.v("TRANSITIONTEST", "CLICKED FROM HOME FRAGMENT --- RENT");
            Log.v("TRANSITIONTEST", "in onClick: " + imageView.getTransitionName());

            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

            OpenRentAnnounceFragment newFragment = OpenRentAnnounceFragment.newInstanceWithImage(card, bitmap, poz);

            newFragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(new DetailsTransition());
            newFragment.setEnterTransition(new Fade());
            newFragment.setExitTransition(new Fade());
            newFragment.setSharedElementReturnTransition(new DetailsTransition());

            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .addSharedElement(imageView, imageView.getTransitionName())
                    .replace(R.id.content_main_without_toolbar, newFragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
        }
    });
```

the `DetailsTransition` class is :

```
public class DetailsTransition extends TransitionSet{

    public DetailsTransition() {
        init();
    }

    /**
     * This constructor allows us to use this transition in XML
     */
    public DetailsTransition(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setOrdering(ORDERING_TOGETHER);
        addTransition(new ChangeBounds())
                .addTransition(new ChangeTransform())
                .addTransition(new ChangeImageTransform());
    }
}
```

i'm assigning different transition names for every view, on adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final HomeUserAnnouncesViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final CardRentAnnounce cardRentAnnounce = cardRentAnnounceArrayList.get(position);
    holder.updateUI(cardRentAnnounce);

    ViewCompat.setTransitionName(holder.rentImage, String.valueOf(position) + "_rent");
    MaterialRippleLayout mlr = (MaterialRippleLayout)holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.search_home_ripple);
    mlr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(listener != null){
                listener.onCardClicked(cardRentAnnounce, holder.rentImage, holder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

the id of image in recyclerview item is identically with the image in fragment

i have followed this tutorial to create the transition, even cloned the project to my pc, run on emulator and trying to do exactly like in the working project but still not working.

how i set the image and imageTransition name in new fragment :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_open_rent_announce, container, false);
    rootView = view;
    image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.detailed_image);
    image.setImageBitmap(currentImageBitmap);
    image.setTransitionName(String.valueOf(pozition) + "_rent");
    Log.v("TRANSITIONTEST", "in onCreateView: " + image.getTransitionName());
    initViews(view);
    setViews();
    return view;
}
```

[Fragment SharedElementsTransition tutorial](https://medium.com/@bherbst/fragment-transitions-with-shared-elements-7c7d71d31cbb#.yy0yim3m4)

both images on recyclerview and detailed fragment are loaded with Glide, but i've tried with local images and still no succes.
What did i'm missing? ask for more code if needed.
Thanks.

the full adapter :

```
package com.minimalart.studentlife.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.drawable.GlideDrawable;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.animation.GlideAnimation;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.GlideDrawableImageViewTarget;
import com.firebase.ui.storage.images.FirebaseImageLoader;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.minimalart.studentlife.R;
import com.minimalart.studentlife.interfaces.OnCardAnnounceClickedListener;
import com.minimalart.studentlife.interfaces.OnImageReadyListener;
import com.minimalart.studentlife.models.CardRentAnnounce;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by ytgab on 23.01.2017.
 */

public class HomeUserAnnouncesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeUserAnnouncesAdapter.HomeUserAnnouncesViewHolder>{

    public OnCardAnnounceClickedListener listener;

    public OnImageReadyListener imageListener;
    private ArrayList<CardRentAnnounce> cardRentAnnounceArrayList;
    private Context context;

    public void setOnCardAnnounceClickedListener(OnCardAnnounceClickedListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void setOnImageReadyListener(OnImageReadyListener imageListener) {
        this.imageListener = imageListener;
    }

    public HomeUserAnnouncesAdapter(ArrayList<CardRentAnnounce> cardRentAnnounceArrayList, Context context) {
        this.cardRentAnnounceArrayList = cardRentAnnounceArrayList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public HomeUserAnnouncesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View announceCard = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_home_user_announces, parent, false);

        return new HomeUserAnnouncesAdapter.HomeUserAnnouncesViewHolder(announceCard);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final HomeUserAnnouncesViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final CardRentAnnounce cardRentAnnounce = cardRentAnnounceArrayList.get(position);
        holder.updateUI(cardRentAnnounce);

        ViewCompat.setTransitionName(holder.rentImage, String.valueOf(position) + "_rent");
        MaterialRippleLayout mlr = (MaterialRippleLayout)holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.search_home_ripple);
        mlr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(listener != null){
                    listener.onCardClicked(cardRentAnnounce, holder.rentImage, holder.getAdapterPosition());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void loadNewData(ArrayList<CardRentAnnounce> list){
        cardRentAnnounceArrayList = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cardRentAnnounceArrayList.size();
    }

    public class HomeUserAnnouncesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView rentTitle;
        private TextView rentRooms;
        private TextView rentPrice;
        private TextView rentLocation;
        private ImageView rentImage;
        private Uri uri;
        StorageReference storageReference;

        private static final String REF_RENT_IMAGES = "rent-images";

        public HomeUserAnnouncesViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            rentTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_home_user_announces_title);
            rentImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailed_image);
        }

        public void updateUI(CardRentAnnounce cardRentAnnounce){
            getImageURL(cardRentAnnounce.getAnnounceID());
            rentTitle.setText(cardRentAnnounce.getTitle());
        }

        public void getImageURL(String announceID){
            FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
            storageReference = firebaseStorage.getReference().child(REF_RENT_IMAGES).child(announceID);
            /*rentImage.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.apartment_inside, context.getTheme()));*/
            Glide.with(context).using(new FirebaseImageLoader()).load(storageReference).into(new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(rentImage){
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, GlideAnimation<? super GlideDrawable> animation) {
                    super.onResourceReady(resource, animation);
                    Log.v("TRANSITIONTEST", "Image ready");
                    if(imageListener != null)
                        imageListener.onImageReady();
                }
            });
        }

        public ImageView getRentImage(){
            return rentImage;
        }

        public Uri getUri() {
          return uri;
        }

        public void setUri(Uri uri) {
            this.uri = uri;
        }
    }
}
```

recyclerview card layout :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/card_home_user_announces"
card:cardElevation="@dimen/card_elevation"
card:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_radius">

<com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/search_home_ripple">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:src="@drawable/apartment_inside"
            android:id="@+id/detailed_image"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:id="@+id/card_home_user_announces_title"
            android:text="Titlu"
            android:textColor="@color/textPrincipal"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:lines="1"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

detailed fragment layout :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.minimalart.studentlife.fragments.OpenRentAnnounceFragment">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/rent_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/rent_detailed_collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/detailed_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:src="@drawable/apartment_inside"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:transitionName="rentTransition"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/detailed_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:title="Titlu">
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/standard_padding"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/standard_padding"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back"
                android:background="@color/full_alpha"
                android:id="@+id/detailed_back_btn"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="30dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/standard_padding"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/standard_padding"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/standard_padding">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/detailed_description"
                    android:textColor="@color/textSecondary"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:text="Descriere: "
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/standard_padding"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/standard_padding"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/standard_padding">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/detailed_rooms"
                    android:textColor="@color/textSecondary"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:text="Număr camere: "
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/standard_padding"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/standard_padding"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/standard_padding">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/detailed_location"
                    android:textColor="@color/textSecondary"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:text="Locatie: "
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/standard_padding"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/standard_padding"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/standard_padding">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/detailed_price"
                    android:textColor="@color/textSecondary"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:text="Pret: "
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/standard_padding"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/standard_padding"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/standard_padding"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/standard_padding">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/detailed_discount"
                    android:textColor="@color/textSecondary"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:text="Discount studenti"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/standard_padding"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/standard_padding"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/standard_padding">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/detailed_seller"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:text="@string/open_rent_seller"
                        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/detailed_contact_user_email"
                            android:background="@color/full_alpha"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:text="@string/open_rent_email"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="@color/textSecondary"
                            android:layout_weight="1">

                        </Button>

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/detailed_contact_user_phone"
                            android:background="@color/full_alpha"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:text="@string/open_rent_phone"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="@color/textSecondary"
                            android:layout_weight="1">

                        </Button>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:id="@+id/rent_detailed_fab"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Have you added the android:transitionName="rentTransition" in both views?

Comment: i have added the view only in the detailed transition image layout, this way was explained in the tutorial

Comment: i tried now using the same transition name but still not working.

Comment: In your detail fragment, what's happening in `initViews()` and `setViews()`?

Comment: Just binding them and loading data in when is donloaded from database